# Funding opportunities as a guest researcher in the US

Tags: funding, united-states, visiting

I have an opportunity for a monthlong stay this summer in a laboratory in the US. I am looking for funding sources that would be available for such a stay.

Looking at the NSF website, I couldn't find anything.

Does anybody know of any opportunities?

Comment: Did you also check if there are funding opportunities at your home institution?

Comment: Sometimes there are funded exchange agreements between specific pairs of countries.